# LLU bad suffix on number

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have  a library that uses `LLU` as a suffix  for a uint64 literal.

Visual studio 2010 (on windows7-64) complains about "bad suffix on number", patching the library to use `LL` works.
Is there some preprocessor definition or properties check box I have to set to enable `LLU` ?

ps anybody know which is the correct behaviour? I have always assumed that whatever VC++ did was the opposite of the standard - but things have improved recently.

Comment: Did you mean 'ULL' ? (no, you probably didn't, but that would at least work)

Comment: Nope they use LLU, I'm not sure if it's some private macro they have defined and forgotten about, or if there is something new in the standard I've missed

Comment: Do you mean uses the suffix as in user-defined literals? Those aren't even in the newest compiler from Microsoft, but they are implemented in GCC and Clang, and all not beginning with an underscore are reserved.

Comment: @chris they have "0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFLLU", remove the U and it works - "LL" is what I thought was correct for a long long, I didn't think you specifed signed-ness in literals

Comment: Yes, LL is long long, but without that, it would be an `int` and overflow it. The only way for that syntax is C++11 user-defined literals.

Comment: @chris - so is LLU in the standard and MS is wrong, or is LL the standard and th elib is wrong?

Comment: It is %llu in the printf() format specifier.  But ULL for the literal suffix, both in GCC and MSVC.

Comment: @MartinBeckett, LL is in the standard, but it's possible to define your own. For example, I could make `"abc"_str` be interpreted as a string. In this case, the only explanation I can think of is that the library makers did that, but with `LLU` instead of `_str`, but it's just *reserved* (not yet used) by the standard because it does not start with an underscore.

Comment: Xcode supports LLU as a postfix for numbers, I use it in loops specifically to remember that Printf's version is that, not ULL, should I make a macro to define that? It compiles ok in Visual Studio 2017 last I checked tho.

Edit: I do C11 though, not C++, maybe the difference is there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the standards I have available to me (drafts only, but of reasonably recent versions), both C++ and C define both "ULL" and "LLU" as valid suffixes for an integer literal. This may be a recent change which VS2010 doesn't follow, but I note that VS2012 does the exact same thing (i.e only ULL works).

There *is* a difference between using a signed and unsigned literal, and that is MSVC's behaviour when you right-shift a signed value. A signed literal will be sign-extended, but an unsigned literal will be padded with zero.

In other words, the following contrived example:

```
unsigned long long l2 = ~0LL >> 5;
unsigned long long l3 = ~0ULL >> 5;
```

...will produce two different values under MSVC.

So if your library is expecting defined behaviour by stipulating unsigned values, then converting them to unsigned values will potentially result in undefined behaviour.

In short, I think MSVC is being a bit naughty in only accepting one form of the suffix, but the best fix is to switch where the 'U' appears, and not to remove it entirely.

Comment: In short: If you want to write portable C++ code, always use the `ULL` suffix for `unsigned long long` literals which will work as expected on Linux and Windows.

Comment: This has been fixed in VS2013.