# The meaning of 1llu in C++

Tags: c++

Consider the i-th column of a binary matrix is denoted with `matrix[i]`. Let `D` be the number of columns of the matrix.

My question: What is the result of the following code. In fact, I can't understand the role of the `1llu` expression.

```
matrix[i]^((1llu << D)-1)
```

Comment: `llu` is a suffix for `unsigned long long int`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LLU bad suffix on number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14588997/llu-bad-suffix-on-number)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is 1LL or 2LL in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16248221/what-is-1ll-or-2ll-in-c-and-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to be looked at from the binary representation.

`1llu` means 1 represented as a `unsigned long long`.

...`0000 0000 0000 0001`

`<< D` shift that `1` left D amount of times (bits)

If D==5 then :

...`0000 0000 0010 0000`

`- 1` subtract 1 from the shifted result ( which gives  1's on the positions 0 ~ D-1)

...`0000 0000 0001 1111`

> The bitwise exclusive OR operator (^) compares each bit of its first operand to the corresponding bit of its second operand. If one bit is 0 and the other bit is 1, the corresponding result bit is set to 1. Otherwise, the corresponding result bit is set to 0.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/bitwise-exclusive-or-operator-hat?view=vs-2019

Comment: `unsigned long long` is a type, not a representation

Comment: @M.M So how would You phrase that sentence to a beginner, so they better understand this concept?

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to explain with an example below:

Example 1: 1 << 34
Example 2: 1llu << 34

If the integer size if 32 bits, then Example 1 would produce 0x0000 0000 as 1 will fall off. Whereas, Example 2 would produce 0x0000 0004 0000 0000

So, it should be seen with the context of the what is the type / size of matrix element.

Comment: The basic idea is true, but if the integer size is 32 bits, 1<<34 invokes undefined behavior. In fact, if naively done on x86/x64, the shift count will wrap around, producing 4 as a result.